# Infinispan/Wildfly: Cannot find a parser for element 'string-keyed-jdbc-store' in namespace

Tags: jdbc, jboss, wildfly, hibernate-search, infinispan

I am trying to configure a JDBC-backed Infinispan cache for storing Hibernate Search indices on Wildfly 10/JBoss EAP 7.  I have installed the Infinispan 8.1.x Wildfly/JBoss modules from infinispan.org within my application server, and I've FINALLY gotten a basic infinispan.xml file working with file persistence, and now I am trying to change it over to use JDBC for persistence.  My infinispan.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.1.xsd
                        urn:infinispan:config:jdbc:8.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-8.0.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.1" xmlns:jdbc="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:8.0">

    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="default-jgroups-udp" path="default-configs/default-jgroups-udp.xml" />
    </jgroups>


    <cache-container name="HibernateSearch" default-cache="default"
        statistics="false" shutdown-hook="DONT_REGISTER">

        <transport stack="default-jgroups-udp" />

        <jmx duplicate-domains="true" />

        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <!-- Cache to store Lucene's file metadata -->
        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata" mode="SYNC"
            remote-timeout="25000">
            <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000"
                concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false" />
            <transaction mode="NONE" />
            <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE" />
            <expiration max-idle="-1" />
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <file-store preload="true" purge="true"
                    path="${jboss.server.temp.dir}/indexes" />
            </persistence>
            <indexing index="NONE" />
            <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000"
                await-initial-transfer="true" />
        </replicated-cache>

        <!-- **************************** -->
        <!-- Cache to store Lucene data -->
        <!-- **************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesData" mode="SYNC"
            remote-timeout="25000">
            <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000"
                concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false" />
            <transaction mode="NONE" />
            <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE" />
            <expiration max-idle="-1" />
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:8.0"
                    fetch-state="false" read-only="false" purge="false">
                    <data-source jndi-url="java:jboss/datasources/InfinispanCacheDS" />
                    <string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false"
                        create-on-start="true" prefix="ISPN_STRING_TABLE">
                        <id-column name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
                        <data-column name="DATA_COLUMN" type="BINARY" />
                        <timestamp-column name="TIMESTAMP_COLUMN" type="BIGINT" />
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </persistence>
            <!-- <persistence passivation="false"> <file-store preload="true" purge="true" 
                path="${jboss.server.temp.dir}/indexes" /> </persistence> -->
            <indexing index="NONE" />
            <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000"
                await-initial-transfer="true" />
        </replicated-cache>

        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <!-- Cache to store Lucene locks -->
        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesLocking" mode="SYNC"
            remote-timeout="25000">
            <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000"
                concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false" />
            <transaction mode="NONE" />
            <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE" />
            <expiration max-idle="-1" />
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <file-store preload="true" purge="true"
                    path="${jboss.server.temp.dir}/indexes" />
            </persistence>
            <indexing index="NONE" />
            <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000"
                await-initial-transfer="true" />
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>

</infinispan>
```

I am also using the following jboss-deployment-structure.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- Core Java/Java EE Dependencies -->
            <module name="javax.transaction.api" export="true" services="import" />

            <!-- JPA/Hibernate Search Dependencies -->
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true" />

            <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine" export="true"
                services="import" slot="5.5" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" export="true"
                services="import" slot="5.5" />

            <module name="org.infinispan.hibernate-search.directory-provider"
                slot="for-hibernatesearch-5.5" export="true" services="import" /><!-- 
                <module name="org.apache.lucene" export="true" services="import" /> <module 
                name="org.infinispan.lucene-directory" slot="ispn-8.1" /> -->

            <module name="org.infinispan.core" slot="ispn-8.1" services="import"
                export="true" />
            <module name="org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc" slot="ispn-8.1"
                services="import" export="true" />
            <module name="org.infinispan.persistence.remote" slot="ispn-8.1"
                services="import" export="true" />

        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

However, when I deploy my application I get the following exception:

```
ISPN000327: Cannot find a parser for element 'string-keyed-jdbc-store' in namespace 'urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:8.0'. Check that your configuration is up-to date for this version of Infinispan.
```

Everything works fine if I change persistence from JDBC to "file".  However, once I put in the JDBC parameters I get the parsing error.  I'm sure I'm doing something minor and stupid to cause this, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to investigate this problem I ended opening a bug report:

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7572

The problem is that I expected the `org.infinispan.core` module to depend on its extensions, but this is not the case. I previously mentioned a wokraround, but editing the module XML files is not enough as there's no easy solution which would be able to maintain the isolation of different modules which need to be isolated.

The problem is fixed now, please upgrade to either Infinispan version `9.0.0.Final` which will contain the fix, or get Infinispan `8.2.7.Final` as I'll backport this fix as well.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for looking into this at such depth.  I'll try your workarounds tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'm making progress!  I added the cache stores to the module.xml file, as recommended.  I now see log statements related to the JDBC cache store, and see the table being created in the database.

Now, however, I'm getting errors like this:

ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand, writing keys [pending_segments_1|0|1048576|<MY ENTITY CLASS>]: org.infinispan.persistence.keymappers.UnsupportedKeyTypeException: Unsupported key type: 'org.infinispan.lucene.ChunkCacheKey' on key: pending_segments_1|0|1048576|<MY ENTITY CLASS>

Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like a different detail of the same kind of problem. You'll need to patch the module.xml of the `org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc` module to allow it to import services from the `org.infinispan.lucene-directory` module: this contains the service which is meant to convert the keys into strings, to allow using the string-keyed storage strategy.

Comment: Hmmm still getting the same Unsupported key type: 'org.infinispan.lucene.ChunkCacheKey' error.  I've added the org.infinispan.lucene-directory module to the module.xml file as recommended.  I also found a reference to defining the key2StringMapperClass property in my infinispan.xml file, but that didn't help.  Should I be using 'binary-keyed-jdbc-store'?  Would that resolve the issue?

Comment: forgot the obvious, sorry :) http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#storing_the_index_in_a_database

Comment: Yes, I added the key2StringMapperClass property as shown in the user guide.  I'm still getting the Unsupported key type... error.

Comment: I suspect that it means one of the components is referring to the implementation from the wrong module. Worth double checking that none of these modules is referring to a library set from a different slot?

Comment: I resolved ISPN-7572, it was quite more complex than I assumed in my comments above. It will be fixed in Infinispan 9.0.0.Final and also backported to 8.2.x . Please try these when released, and thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Thank you. I'll edit my answer as the workarounds I mentioned are not enough.